# How to create stacked pagination in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pagination

How to achieve the UI as shown in the image below?

I wanted to create a form with steps, by clicking next button it will swipe and open next form and will update the number of stacked pages as shown.

[image] [image]

Comment: question unclear because OP has not given any sign of effort (in form of examples of code etc) please reffer to the following links: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

For making this type of UI you need to use Background image and UIPageControl. And you have to make other UI elements like text fields and button with code. You should be careful about frames.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer, and created the same UI using Koloda library in objective-c
https://github.com/wang9262/Koloda-ObjC